# k-edge-connectivity

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

For every positive integer $k$ construct an infinite family of
graphs G with $\lambda(G)=k$ without using parallel edges in the
construction. 
I can't construct infinite family of graphs that satisfies the given condition. hint is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: use as many edges as you can. (For edge connectivity.)

Comment: @Lorenzo Najt, without using parallel edges is it really possible?

Comment: Yes. You may want to use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger%27s_theorem to prove lower bounds on $k$-edge connectedness of the examples you try, although it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For some $n>k$, draw two copies of $K_n$.  Can you think of a way to add edges to that graph such that its edge-connectivity would be $k$?

Comment: For example, on  two copies of $K_3$, if we connect their vertices to each other by an edge we get a graph $G$ with $deg(v)=3, \forall v\in V(G)$ and it's $\lambda(G)=3$, now $n=3=k$ ?

Comment: @KosovoBuda Sure.  You can do the same with two copies of $K_4$.  Connect three vertices of one copy to three vertices of the other copy, and you have another 3-edge-connected graph.

Comment: @Mattewdaly, Thanks a lot for your time and contributions.